# Inquiry about writing plugins for Autodesk Maya

Tags: c++, plugins, sdk, maya, autodesk

I am very interested in CG. However, it might be time consuming to write a program based on OpenSceneGraph .So, I was wondering of writing a plugin for Maya and use the strong rendering of Maya to apply my algorithm.

I have downloaded the student version of Maya. However, still not sure:

1. Is it free to develop plugins based on Maya SDK if only for academic purpose?
2. How "deep" I can change the software?(Can I change the meshing result by changing the meshing algorithm? Can I add a new docking widget in the Graphics Scene?)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, for plugins you need a id range if you wish to share them. Its not really easy tough. Maya has a really deep hardcore philosophy, if you try to use Maya the wrong way it will totally freak at you. After that point everything you do will be a serious uphill battle.
2. Meshing. Depends a bit on what meshing stage in Maya your 
   talking about? The one used by the view port? Sure, not really a stroll in the park. The one used by mentalray, perhaps, not sure, tough you can always emit the result.

   Docking widget, sure no problem.